# Insert Javascript in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am using visual basic for coding. In my form I have a delete button for deleting a record.
Now I want to show a Confirm msgbox using javascript instead of using visual basic.

What is the javascipt code for the msgbox &
Where do I insert this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this..

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm(&quot;Are you sure you want to delete&quot;)" />
```

If you want in code behind

```
imgbtn.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ?');");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:LinkButton 
    ID="LinkButton1" 
    runat="server" 
    OnClick="LinkButton_Click"
    OnClientClick ="return confirm('Are you sure to delete ?')"
    Text="Delete" 
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');" />
```